# Can I tell the voltage of High Power Transmission lines by its Type?

Tags: voltage, transmission-line, emf

I am moving to Foster City, CA and am looking at an apartment about 550 feet from these power lines: https://www.google.com/maps/@37.562322,-122.27068,3a,75y,153.58h,99.44t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1smflaesKSGl9ZTGIfEao93g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1

I am trying to figure out the max voltage these lines carry to do research on what a safe distance would be to live from them (worried about EMFs).  From my research I am guessing these lines can transmit 275kv - 400kv.  But information on the internet about these towers is hard to come by and not very clear.

Is it possible to tell the max voltage carried over lines by tower type?  Also any resources about safe living distances by transmission line type would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* determine the voltage imposed on the wires.  This is done by looking at the insulators holding the wires off the tower.  The more discs, the higher the voltage.  Those look like pretty high voltage, for long distance distribution.

However, voltage has nothing to do with the electromagnetic fields.  That is determined by the *current* in the wires.  That's not so easy to determine.

However, since you are interested in the electromagnetic fields at your location, the power company has an EMF meter they use to measure such a thing.  I don't know the arrangements for this, but call them and ask.  They came out and did a survey at my house when I sold it, so I know the service is available.  I don't recall having to pay for it.

Comment: If your distance is over 650 feet from the nearest high-voltage power line, you have nothing to worry about.